# If an agent performs an action, does she apply her passive effects?

Tags: rome-2-total-war

In Rome 2, agents have a wide range of active and passive abilities or actions.  For example, [a dignitary can corrupt](http://totalwar.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_Dignitary_Skills_and_Traits_%28Total_War:_Rome_II%29) a non-friendly province, and thus reduce tax income, simply by standing around in that territory every turn.

That leads me to wonder if using an active agent skill, like cultural propaganda, interferes with a passive agent skill, like corruption.

Do actions or movement prevent or reduce the effect of a passive agent ability?